# Awesomium не загружает страницу

Tags: c#

```
web = WebCore.CreateWebView(500, 500, session);
    web.Source = new Uri("https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=0");
    web.DocumentReady += webok;
   while(!ready)
     {
            ;
      }
}

public void webok(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hz();

    ready = true;
}
```

Работая с компонентом веб браузера *awesomium* столкнулся с такой проблемой. Загружая страницу ставлю событие полной загрузки на функцию, в которой значение глобальную переменную меняю на `true` тем временем в основной функции ставлю бесконечный `while` цикл на проверку данной переменной. Но почему-то страница не загружается пока идёт этот цикл. Приложение Windows Form

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

И не будет загружаться. Вы же бесконечным циклом заблокировали поток, в котором работает контрол. Вам наверное говорили, что холостые циклы гонять нельзя?

Переместите тот код, который вам нужен после загрузки документа, в `webok`. Уберите флаг `ready`. Подумайте о том, что произойдёт, если документ не загрузился (вам нужно корректно обработать ошибку).